# Convert Bazaar repo to SVN

Tags: svn, bazaar

I have written some python scripts that take advantage of pysvn to analyze a project. I would like to run these on a project that is now in a bazaar repo so I was wondering how I could get a copy of the bazaar repo on my machine and then translate it to a svn standard so pysvn can use it.

I found some documentation on going SVN to Bazaar but not the other way around. Is it possible?

Comment: Bazaar written in Python, so you can write similar script to analyze bzr repo using native bzrlib API.

Comment: Original topic question: see [How to export a baazar branch into a new subversion repository...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932302/how-to-export-a-baazar-branch-into-a-new-subversion-repository-and-then-pull-pus) with working answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the scripts are in Python?  You're in luck as Bazaaar is written in Python, so [bzrlib](http://starship.python.net/crew/mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.html) can be used to analyse a repository.

That said, with bzr-svn installed on Ubuntu 9.04, I am getting "fetch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch_spec'" when I attempt to "bzr push" to a folder in a subversion repo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bzr-svn plugin to push bzr branch into svn repo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it for Bazaar, but I have used [Tailor](http://progetti.arstecnica.it/tailor) to keep an svn repo in sync with a git repo.