# replay svn repo to bazaar

Tags: svn, migration, bazaar

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380756/convert-bazaar-repo-to-svn) asks how to convert from bazaar to svn. I need to do the opposite. I need to extract all the commit history from a svn repo and "replay" it on a bazaar repo. I will then drop the svn development and continue on bazaar.

Any hints ?

*Edit*:

Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing as follows:

1) Performing synchronization of the remote svn repo with the following script (adapted from [here](http://pogopixels.com/blog/dumping-a-svn-repository-from-a-remote-url/#comment-153))

```
REPO_PATH=$HOME/tmp/repo
REPO_PATH_NUX=file://$HOME/tmp/repo
REPO_URL=https://example.com/repo/path

mkdir $REPO_PATH
svnadmin create $REPO_PATH
echo '#!/bin/sh' > $REPO_PATH/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod +x $REPO_PATH/hooks/pre-revprop-change
svnsync init $REPO_PATH_NUX $REPO_URL
svnsync sync $REPO_PATH_NUX
```

2) dumped the synchronized local repository with `svnadmin dump repo >dumpfile`

3) ran `svn2bzr dumpfile bzrrepo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Bazaar migration guide](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrMigration), especially [converting from Subversion](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrMigration#Subversion%20%28svn%29). Since you don't intend to continue development in the SVN repo, you can use the fastest option, `bzr-fastimport`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bzr-svn plugin for one-time migration easily.