# How to export a bazaar branch into a new subversion repository and then pull/push from it

Tags: svn, version-control, bazaar, bzr-svn

I've been working on a project, using Bazaar as a version control system.
Now I have to work with people offshore, and they only want to use SVN.

What I have:

- My `bazaar` branch with its files and revisions.
- A brand new `subversion` repository.

What I want:

- My bazaar branch with its files and revisions.
- The subversion repo with the same files and revisions (includings dates and commit messages).
- Being able to `pull` / `push` from/to the SVN using `bzr`.

I managed to copy the branch into the svn repo using tailor, but bazaar won't recognized it (Branches have no common ancestor).

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible using bzr-svn. After you've created your Subversion repository, simply push to trunk:

```
$ svnadmin create /my/svn/repo
$ cd /my/bzr/branch
$ bzr push /my/svn/repo/trunk
Pushed up to revision X.
```

After that, you should be able to pull from the trunk whenever they have made changes. You can push your changes using `bzr push`, possibly after rebasing them if the branches have diverged (using `bzr rebase` in the bzr-rewrite plugin).

Comment: Yes, bzr-svn is definitely the way to go! I personally wouldn't go the rebase route though: if you rebase *one* branch, you'll probably need to rebase a bunch of other branches. Instead, I would just make a branch of the SVN trunk and `bzr merge` your changes into that, then `bzr push` back to SVN. (If jelmer tells you that won't work, though, he's probably right: he *is* the author of bzr-svn, after all!)

Comment: This worked for me when I added "--overwrite" key (otherwise I was being reported about "diverged" branches).